# I'm trying to get my registration site running but in the terminal I've got an error

Tags: python, html, mongodb

I've got
**TypeError: Object of type builtin_function_or_method is not JSON serializable**

What does this mean exactly?

Comment: It means you're calling `json.dump` on a _function_, instead of _the value returned from a function_.  I assume you left off the parentheses `()` from a function call somewhere.  But you haven't shown us the code, so all I can do is guess.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to serialize a function, not a value. Most likely this is due to you not calling the function, like this:

```py
def my_function():
    return "Hello, World"

serialize(my_function) # Incorrect
serialize(my_function()) # Correct
```

Comment: I see.
I've got  **in dumps
    rv = _json.dumps(obj, **kwargs)**
as an error, but how do I fix this? Its relating to my init file which isn't editable so how do I solve this?